# Как сделать переход с категории на определенную запись?

Tags: wordpress

Помогите пожалуйста реализовать следующую задачу.
Создал свою таксономию, создал свой тип записи. Хочу реализовать следующую структуру страницы:
Есть автомобили - 
БМВ(категория, произвольная таксономия) =>Определенная марка, которая относится именно к этой категории (краткое описание) => Сама статья (single-car.php)
Подскажите пожалуйста как можно реализовать такую структуру.
Я пробовал выводить список категорий с помощью функции get_the_terms, потом с помощью функции get_term_link получал ссылку на элемент таксономии, вот на этом моменте что то идет не так, не могу понять какой файл нужно отредактировать что бы выводилась нужная информация, сейчас за вывод отвечает файл archive.php, создаю свой файл, однако ни чего не работает. Чувствую что полез в какие то дебри, может кто то подскажет как можно реализовать подобную затею. буду очень признателен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите, чтобы за вывод списка терминов таксономии отвечал файл, отличный от `archive.php`, то вам стоит создать для этой цели файл `taxonomy.php` (будет работать для любых созданных вами таксономий), либо `taxonomy-$taxonomy.php`, где `$taxonomy` - имя вашей таксономии (например, если она называется "cars", то это будет `taxonomy-cars.php`), в таком случае файл будет работать только для таксономии "cars".

Полезно будет обратить внимание на инфографику по иерархии файлов для wordpress-темы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо. попробую работать в этом направлении